# create new window/area for blender

Tags: python, add-on

example: animation nodes addon; creates a new window so that you can edit your animations (or whatever they're called) in called the animtation node editor.

does anyone know how I can make my own window/area (if you dont know what i mean, examples of window/areas: 3d view, shader editor, geometry nodes etc)

Comment: This is super easy, and it’s talked about in docs.blender.org

Comment: could you send a link? i don't know what to look for

Comment: You can create custom node editors, but you can't create any other custom editor type afaik.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new window with a specific editor in it, or create a new type of editor with the python API?